# How to store the details about modified documents in another collection in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to store the details of the modified fields in a collection and store those details in the another collection. For example if i update the field "Status" the new value and old value should be stored in another collection along with the _id of the modified documents. Is it possible to do it? I know that we cannot use Trigger in MongoDB. I tried to used log files for it. But not able to get the old value of updated document using it. Please let me know the possible way. I'm very much stuck here.

Comment: You can utilize the callback function whenever you are trying to update the document and save the respected fields and values into an another document which keeps the record of the updated value.

Comment: @saubar I think you are saying to do it from Application side. Is it possible to do it from DB side. Or any tools available to do it?

Comment: it depends upon the technology you are using on server side, if you are using javascript then you can achieve this notion through mongoose ODM, it have the concept of 'pre' .